# Where does the uncertainty of the "true" $p_{*}(y|x)$ come from?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, assumptions, posterior

You'll often see the goal of a statistical estimation problem as being to fit a model such that it $\approx p_{*}(y|x)$ where $p_{*}(y|x)$ is the "true distribution of the data".

**My question is**: what uncertainty is possessed in this "true distribution of the data"? Does it assume infinite training data...in which case it only possesses "aleatoric" uncertainty?

Put another way...assuming correct model specification, if we have little data but we fit a Bayesian model such that the model uncertainty is perfectly accounted for, does that model's posterior predictive $p(y|x, \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ closely approximate $p_{*}(y|x)$?

Comment: It's not clear how the first part of your question relates to the last paragraph. The true probability has no uncertainty because it's true, there is also no data or training involved.

Comment: "The true probability has no uncertainty because it's true". Then why describe this "truth" as a probability distribution...which specifically aims to represent uncertainty. Why not call it the true y=f(x)? I do think the last thing you said answers my question somewhat. If there is no data involved then it implies that the uncertainty in $p_{*}(y|x)$ is irreducible. Therefore, having little data but a good Bayesian model may not in fact approximate this "true" distribution.

Comment: In statistics, we consider the observed phenomena as random variables following some probability distributions. If your data would be produced by a constant function, there would be no uncertainty, so you would not need statistics for the problem. You should start with an introductory statistics handbook as your question is seems by a misunderstanding of the underlying concepts.